# Add Navigation Drawer to Exsisting Andrdoid Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

I'm developing Android Google Map project.

Here is what i wanted.

Default screen is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxIZa.png) and when drawer page must like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PSlN.png)

I already did the google map part and I created a new Navigation Drawer Activity. How Am I suppose to connect these 2? I mean, how can I set the screen under the navigation drawer to my map page?

Already tried,

```
@Override
```

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1());
tx.commit();
```

}

Did not work.

Please help. This may be a silly question. but, I'm new to Andrdoid.

Thanks

-Edit - 
 Here is the `activity_maps.xml`

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Here is the `activity_navigation.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/activity_maps"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

Here is the `drawer_header.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Abc"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the `drawer.xml` (menu)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    </group>

    <item android:title="Sub items">
        <menu>

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I can not find what happened. But, I'm still getting the same error with this code.

Comment: See this. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Sorry. I know how to add a Navigation Drawer Activity. I need more.

Comment: I think you can try to use `NavigationView` in the `Android Design Support Library`. Just import the library and add `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` to your layout. For more details, please refer [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Comment: @bjiang, Followed the tutorial in your link. Didn't help. Can you have a look at edited part?

Comment: The `headerLayout` you need to create, so for the full code source about `Android design support library` just refer to [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare). And [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/nav_header.xml) is the part of `header_layout` in that sample.

Comment: @bjiang , Please see the edited post. Could't run the project. Getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps.

1. Right click on your Android Studio project
2. Select New-> Activity -> Navigation Drawer Activity
3. Give a name and create the Navigation Drawer activity
4. open `activity_drawer.xml`
5. Add following code `<include layout="@layout/activity_maps"/>`
6. You'll get your answer

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer. Works like charm

Comment: yeah idea is great, also need to use your some personal code shifting to associated class.